# Wordpress - posts on subpage 'blog'

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing, blogs, posts

I have a problem with posts on the subpage:
- if the home page = index and page with posts = blog then the blog page displays me the index page ... the templates have been set
Anyone have an idea? Please ...

Comment: Create a Page. then follow the instruction to set the Page as your posts https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page, and your homepage need to be a static page to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined default blog page in admin (Setting->reading->post page), therefore index page display.

Please deselect post page from admin, Create new page and select template from there.

Comment: If you have selected a template and deselect default post page from admin. its should be work. index.php works only one condition if you have selected default blog page from setting.